# ASP.NET MVC Form Validation fails each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

Upon successful validation of the form, I'm unable to redirect the form. Please help me. I'm very new to ASP.NET and MVC Concepts.
I have given below the model, the view and the controller. The Index page displays login information, and I'm submitting the form to the same page. If there are no errors, I have to redirect the form to a different page. This is what I'm trying to do. But even If I provide valid login information, the form doesn't redirect to the specified page.

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProject.Models
{
  public class LoginModel
  {  
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserCode is Required.")]
    public string UserCode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required.")]
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
[HandleError]
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    // GET
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Transfer", "Home");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult UpgradeBrowser()
    {
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Models.LoginModel>" %>


<div id="LoginBox">
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FrmLoginUser" }))
   { %>
    <table class="TblForm">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="UserName">UserCode</label></td>
            <td><%= Html.TextBox("UserCode", "", new { id = "UserCode" })%></td>
            <td><%= Html.ValidationMessage("UserCode", new { @class = "ValidationError" })%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Password">Password</label></td>
            <td><%= Html.Password("Password", "", new { id="Password" })%></td>
            <td><%= Html.ValidationMessage("Password", new { @class = "ValidationError" })%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<% } %>

</div> <!-- #LoginBox -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **actually return** the result of the `RedirectToAction` call. Change `RedirectToAction` to be `return RedirectToAction` in your controller `HttpPost` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Transfer", "Home");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Dude, you are awesome. Thank you so much for the help. Successfully working.